# Create an Instagram type feed using GridBagLayout & JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

How to create an Instagram type feed using `GridBagLayout` and `JScrollPane` in Swing?

oki so i am trying to create a gallery kinda thing that looks similar to the instagram feed (three images side by side and rows can be as many).

i tried doing it using the gridbag layout to the jpanel and then add this jpanel to the jscrollpane.

//just the main peice of code

```
       rightbottom=new JPanel();       
    rightbottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    rightbottom.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c1=new GridBagConstraints();
    c1.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    gallery = new JScrollPane(rightbottom);


 gallery.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

//aetherfirst,aethersecond..etc are my image labels custom to my preferred sizes

```
    c1.gridx=0;
    c1.gridy=0;
    c1.weightx=1;
    c1.weighty=1;
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    rightbottom.add(aetherfirst,c1);

    c1.gridx=1;
    c1.gridy=0;
    rightbottom.add(aethersecond,c1);
    c1.gridx=2;
    c1.gridy=0;
    rightbottom.add(aetherthird,c1);
    c1.gridx=0;
    c1.gridy=1;
    rightbottom.add(aetherfourth,c1);
    c1.gridx=1;
    c1.gridy=1;
    rightbottom.add(aetherfifth,c1);
    c1.gridx=2;
    c1.gridy=1;
    rightbottom.add(aethersixth,c1);
    c1.gridx=0;
    c1.gridy=2;
    rightbottom.add(aetherseventh,c1);
```

it didn't come as expected , every time i add more images instead of using the space such that i could scroll down to see the images not seen on the visible space, it shrinks the other images to fit all of it in the same visible space.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `GridBagLayout`? It can be achieved simply using `FlowLayout` or `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use GridBagLayout? It can be achieved simply using `FlowLayout` (horizontal scrolling) or `GridLayout` (vertical scrolling).

See the following example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class InstaFeedSimulation{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JScrollPane flowPanelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(new FlowFeed());
        JFrame flowFrame = new JFrame("Instagram Feed Panel Simulation");
        flowFrame.setBounds(200, 200, 187, 120);
        flowFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        flowFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        flowFrame.add(flowPanelScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        flowFrame.setVisible(true);
        //
        JScrollPane gridPanelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(new GridFeed());
        JFrame gridFrame = new JFrame("Instagram Feed Panel Simulation");
        gridFrame.setBounds(400, 400, 190, 250);
        gridFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gridFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gridFrame.add(gridPanelScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gridFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class FlowFeed extends JPanel{
    private Color[] COLORS = new Color[] {Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN,
              Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED,
              Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE};

    public FlowFeed() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        //
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            JPanel aPanel = new JPanel();
            aPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            aPanel.setBackground(COLORS[rand.nextInt(COLORS.length)]);
            this.add(aPanel);
        }
    }
}

class GridFeed extends JPanel{
    private Color[] COLORS = new Color[] {Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN,
                                  Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED,
                                  Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE};
    public GridFeed() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,3,3,3));
        //
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            JPanel aPanel = new JPanel();
            aPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            aPanel.setBackground(COLORS[rand.nextInt(COLORS.length)]);
            this.add(aPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, tell me if I got the idea wrong.

Comment: There is no reason to extend JPanel for either of these use cases.  Just construct a JPanel directly and set its layout.

Comment: @VGR: You are right and it isn't necessary to extend `JPanel` for this simple example. I was only suggesting OP that a `FeedPanel` can be child of `JPanel` and it can encapsulate all the necessary functionalities and properties of such panel, including the layout management, further event handling and event propagation in the future.

Comment: thanks a lot it , your code did hat i wanted it to somewhat do but , i want the size to be dynamic so that if i add more images later on i can modify also if there are fewer images , i noticed before when i used grid layout it for some reason dosent maintain the 3 columns. eg when i added 4 images to the feed instead of 3 in first row and 1 in the second it became 2 in each row. still new to this so trying to understand thanks

Comment: also this dosent work for images put in jlabels for some reason the jlabels will resize too fit in the visible section